# Strategies for keeping two mySQL databases (in separate locations) in sync?

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the best way to bi-directionally synchronize dynamic data in real time using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325791/which-is-the-best-way-to-bi-directionally-synchronize-dynamic-data-in-real-time)

I need advice:

**How do I keep 2 mySQL databases (same structure) synced up across 2 locations?**

*What am I doing:*
I am creating an application for a business with two locations. They need to share/update information in a database BUT the proprietor wants it to be internal not external, as he is worried about being able to run in case of an internet outage.

*My Strategy so far:*
I've set up two servers (one in each location) Each running local Apache + MySQL. The webapp is NOT accessible over the internet, only locally. The mySQL is accessible over SSL via the internet (with a complex password).

The local webapp runs and interacts with local mySQL for reads. For writes, it writes locally then to the remote server (writing 2x).

I am concerned about creating duplicate/corrupted entries when record ids might be duplicated / different, etc... This is why I don't rely on record id, but rather on a separate unique number that I control (not auto-increment).

Bottom line... This is the best I could come up with after doing extensive research. Am I right? Or can someone offer advice?

Comment: Doesn't mysql have built-in distribution capabilities?

Comment: Take a look at "multi-master" [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) and auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset.

Answer (score 5):

This is called **replication**, and MySQL (like any mature database management system) has native support for it. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Although bi-directional (i.e. the master-slave graph is cyclic) replication is known to be **dangerous/difficult** and documented as such. Although MySQL will ensure there are no replication loops, data consistency might be at risk (esp. when using auto-increment columns).

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for distributed transactions. MySQL offers XA transaction support (see [their documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html) for more information).